# Resposta retrofit chegando como null

Tags: android, web-service, retrofit, okhttp

Estou tentando realizar uma chamada via retrofit de uma lista de objetos (Cadastros) e no HttpLogginInterceptor a resposta está aparecendo normalmente. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Minha chamada:

```
CadastroApi cadastroApi = retrofit.create(CadastroApi.class);

            Call<List<Cadastro>> callCadastros =cadastroApi.getCadastro(token);
            callCadastros.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cadastro>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<List<Cadastro>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    List<Cadastro> cadastroList = response.body();

                    if (cadastroList != null){

                        Log.i("ACTTOKEN","Resultado da resposta cadastro: "+cadastroList.get(1).getCpf_cnpj());

                        // Insere o cadastro no banco de dados
                        try {
                            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(TokenActivity.this,token);
                            SQLiteDatabase conn = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            RepositorioCadastro repositorioCadastro = new RepositorioCadastro(conn);

                            for (Cadastro cadastro : cadastroList){

                                repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(cadastro);


                            }
                        }catch (SQLiteException e){

                            Log.i("ACTTOKEN","Erro ao inserir cadastro: "+e);

                        }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    // Em caso de erro
                    Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro retrofit ao baixar Cadastros: " + t.getCause());

                }

                });
```

Minha API:

```
public interface CadastroApi {

    @POST("Cadastro_Down.php?token=")
    Call<List<Cadastro>> getCadastro(@Query("token") String token);

}
```

Resposta do WebService

```
[{
    "id": "-1",
    "data": null,
    "nome": "CLIENTE VENDA R\u00c1PIDA",
    "cpf_cnpj": "1111111111",
    "email": "LETICIA_L_CARVALHO@IBEST.COM.BR",
    "fone": null,
    "celular": null,
    "fax": null,
    "status": "1",
    "obs": null,
    "municipal": null,
    "estadual": null,
    "rg": null,
    "foto": null,
    "sexo": null,
    "data_nas": null,
    "nome_fantasia": null,
    "forca_venda": null,
    "id_vendedor": "2",
    "limite": "0.00",
    "casado": "",
    "pai": "",
    "mae": "",
    "fiado": "0.00"
}, {
    "id": "91",
    "data": "2016-01-09",
    "nome": "SAMUEL RAUL PINTO",
    "cpf_cnpj": "65573998455",
    "email": "SAMUEL_R_PINTO@CLINICAMEDICOFACIL.COM.BR",
    "fone": "(69) 2925-9737",
    "celular": "(69) 8508-5128",
    "fax": "(69) 2925-9737",
    "status": "1",
    "obs": "f7WDsqCrfc",
    "municipal": "",
    "estadual": "",
    "rg": "37.922.970-5",
    "foto": "",
    "sexo": "MASCULINO",
    "data_nas": "1994-06-10",
    "nome_fantasia": "",
    "forca_venda": null,
    "id_vendedor": "1",
    "limite": "10000.00",
    "casado": "N\u00c3O",
    "pai": "AGENOR",
    "mae": "RORAIMA",
    "fiado": "5000.00"
}]
```

Comment: Pode ser que ele receba a resposta mas não consiga transformar a resposta no seu objeto, isso pode acontecer por tipos incompatíveis no JSON, por exemplo, se `status` for um Boolean na sua classe java, não aceitará `"1"` como valor, o mesmo se tentar atribuir um null à um inteiro por exemplo. tente pegar esse mesmo JSON sem nenhum null e veja se recebe normalmente.